# how to aggregate deep nested objects into on key in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

i have a object that looks like below sample object

```
{
    "op1": {
        "color": [
            "red",
            "yellow"
        ],
        "size":[
            1,3
        ]
    },
    "op2": {
        "color": [
            "black",
            "green"
        ],
        "size":[
            1,2
        ]
    },
    "op3": {
        "color": [
            "black"
        ]
    }
}
```

then i need to aggregate all key's values into one key like this
note: properties will be dynamic

```
{
    "all": {
        "color": [
            "red",
            "yellow",
            "black",
            "green"
        ],
        "size": [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ]
    }
}
```

i tired lodash merge but merge works on parent level

Comment: Is the properties has fixed name `color` and `size`, or they have dynamic name and level?

Comment: no properties will be dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Get the object's values, and then spread into `_.mergeWith()`.

In the customizer function `_.mergeWith()` check if the 1st value (`a`) is an array. If it is an array, use `_.union()` to get an array of unique value from both `a` and `b`. If it's not an array, return `undefined`, so the default `_.merge()` algorithm would be used to combine the items.

```js
const { mergeWith, values, isArray, union } = _

const fn = obj => mergeWith({}, ...values(obj), (a, b) => 
  isArray(a) ? union(a, b) : undefined
)

const obj = {"op1":{"color":["red","yellow"],"size":[1,3]},"op2":{"color":["black","green"],"size":[1,2]},"op3":{"color":["black"]}}

const result = fn(obj)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```